# compile & execute Chromium failed due to SUID sandbox issue

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, sandbox, suid

#### What I'm trying to do :

Compile and run Chromium source code on Ubuntu 13.10

#### Steps I've taken :

```
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
add to bashrc :
    export PATH="$PATH":/home/y0.kim/project/depot_tools    
    export CHROME_DEVEL_SANDBOX=/usr/local/sbin/chrome-devel-sandbox
fetch --nohooks chromium --nosvn=True
git checkout master
build/install-build-deps.sh
git pull
gclient sync
ninja -C out/Debug chrome chrome_sandbox
build/update-linux-sandbox.sh
out/Debug/chrome               -> Fail
out/Debug/chrome --no-sandbox  -> Fail
```

#### Problem :

get the source code and compiled without problem.
However, when i execute chrome, i have below error

**normal execution**

```
:~/project2/src$ out/Debug/chrome
The setuid sandbox provides API version 1, but you need 0
Please read https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment.

[37555:37588:0616/152604:FATAL:browser_main_loop.cc(207)] <unknown>: Command line `dbus-launch --autolaunch=f271cc756e9c41e457760b8c00000496 --binary-syntax --close-stderr' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.\n
#0 0x7f570456a39d base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
#1 0x7f57045bc51d logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage()
#2 0x7f5707e45cef content::(anonymous namespace)::GLibLogHandler()
#3 0x7f5701c20f61 g_logv
#4 0x7f5701c21172 g_log
#5 0x7f56f5240d2a <unknown>
#6 0x7f56f5241087 <unknown>
#7 0x7f5701c19d13 g_main_context_dispatch
#8 0x7f5701c1a060 <unknown>
#9 0x7f5701c1a45a g_main_loop_run
#10 0x7f56f524098b <unknown>
#11 0x7f5701c3b9b5 <unknown>
#12 0x7f56fdfd0e9a start_thread
#13 0x7f56fc1853fd clone

Aborted (core dumped)
```

**execution with --no-sandbox**

```
~/project2/src$ out/Debug/chrome --no-sandbox
[19653:19653:0616/152447:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(161)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
[19653:19656:0616/152447:FATAL:browser_main_loop.cc(207)] <unknown>: Command line `dbus-launch --autolaunch=f271cc756e9c41e457760b8c00000496 --binary-syntax --close-stderr' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.\n
#0 0x7f8f13bbe39d base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
#1 0x7f8f13c1051d logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage()
#2 0x7f8f17499cef content::(anonymous namespace)::GLibLogHandler()
#3 0x7f8f11274f61 g_logv
#4 0x7f8f11275172 g_log
#5 0x7f8f05095d2a <unknown>
#6 0x7f8f05096087 <unknown>
#7 0x7f8f1126dd13 g_main_context_dispatch
#8 0x7f8f1126e060 <unknown>
#9 0x7f8f1126e45a g_main_loop_run
#10 0x7f8f0509598b <unknown>
#11 0x7f8f1128f9b5 <unknown>
#12 0x7f8f0d624e9a start_thread
#13 0x7f8f0b7d93fd clone

Aborted (core dumped)
:~/project2/src$ [0616/152448:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(277)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly
```

#### steps i've tried to fix the problem:

1. went to https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment
2. read it
3. built chrome with chrome_sandbox again

   - `ninja -C out/Debug chrome chrome_sandbox`
4. executed `build/update-linux-sandbox.sh` again
5. checked again if `~/.bashrc` have below line

   - `export CHROME_DEVEL_SANDBOX=/usr/local/sbin/chrome-devel-sandbox`

#### what i would like to know:

1. What should I do to execute Chrome on above situation?
2. What would be the reason that `--no-sandbox` option did not work?

any input would be highly appreciated.

Young.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue and when i run chrome with this flag it worked fine

```
 --disable-setuid-sandbox
```

Answer (score 4):

This error message...

```
The setuid sandbox provides API version 1, but you need 0
```

...implies that *your setuid binary is out of date* hence the program was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

---

As per the documentation in [Linux SUID Sandbox Development](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/docs/linux/suid_sandbox_development.md) [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) needs a `SUID` helper binary to turn on the sandbox on Linux. In majority of the cases you can install the proper sandbox for you using the command:

```
build/update-linux-sandbox.sh
```

This program will install the proper *sandbox* for you in `/usr/local/sbin` and tell you to update your `.bashrc` if required.

However, there can be some exceptions as an example, if your `setuid` binary is out of date, you will get messages such as:

```
The setuid sandbox provides API version X, but you need Y
You are using a wrong version of the setuid binary!
```

In these cases, you need to follow the steps below:

- Build `chrome_sandbox` whenever you build chrome (`ninja -C xxx chrome chrome_sandbox` instead of `ninja -C xxx chrome`)
- After building, execute `update-linux-sandbox.sh`.

  ```
  # needed if you build on NFS!
  sudo cp out/Debug/chrome_sandbox /usr/local/sbin/chrome-devel-sandbox
  sudo chown root:root /usr/local/sbin/chrome-devel-sandbox
  sudo chmod 4755 /usr/local/sbin/chrome-devel-sandbox
  ```
- Finally, you have to include the following line in your `~/.bashrc` (or `.zshenv`):

  ```
  export CHROME_DEVEL_SANDBOX=/usr/local/sbin/chrome-devel-sandbox
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find the documentations in:

- [Issue 369100: ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(233) NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=369100)
- [Issue 318646: Chrome won't start after update to latest stable version](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=318646)
- [Issue 598454: Stop checking for the setuid sanbox binary on desktop Linux](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=598454)

---

### tl; dr

[Linux SUID Sandbox](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/docs/linux/suid_sandbox.md)

Comment: Please note that, as the links point out, SUID sandboxing is on its way out and being replaced by unprivileged namespaces